# Deploy a C# + Linq console application?

Tags: c#, linq, deployment, console-application

**How do I compile and deploy a C#/.NET3.5 console application that uses linq?**

I wrote a console app "ExcelDriver" in Visual Studio 2008 (New Project > Visual C# > Windows > Console Application) that uses Excel.Interop and linq-to-sql. [1]

```
Build menu  > Clean ExcelDriver
Build menu > Build ExcelDriver
```

This puts files in the folder C:\dev\VisualStudio2008\ExcelDriver\ExcelDriver\bin\Release\

```
Directory of C:\dev\VisualStudio2008\ExcelDriver\ExcelDriver\bin\Release

03/30/2011  02:17 PM            12,800 ExcelDriver.exe
03/25/2011  12:14 PM               411 ExcelDriver.exe.config
03/30/2011  02:17 PM            26,112 ExcelDriver.pdb
03/30/2011  01:32 PM         1,093,632 Interop.Excel.dll
03/30/2011  01:32 PM           417,792 Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core.dll
5 File(s)      1,550,747 bytes

C:\dev\VisualStudio2008\ExcelDriver\ExcelDriver\bin\Release>ExcelDriver.exe
```

Which works perfectly when I run it.

But when I copy these 5 files to my co-worker's computer and run, it fails and complains that it can't find System.Data.Linq.  This also happens if I copy the entire project folder over.

Here's the error message on the coworker machine

```
C:\ExcelDriver>ExcelDriver.exe

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or ass
embly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c
561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specifie
d.
File name: 'System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b
77a5c561934e089'
   at ExcelDriver.Program.Main(String[] args)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\M
icrosoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure lo
gging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fus
ion!EnableLog].


C:\ExcelDriver>
```

**Clearly I am missing something when I compile the app.  What must I do to get ALL the assemblies and whatnot into one place so I can deploy to other machines?**

[1] It's been a very unhappy experience for me.  Learn from my pain... If anyone ever suggests to you to write a C# app to control Excel RUN AWAY. (It's too late for me.  Save yourself!)

Comment: He's probably missing .NET 3.5 which you'll need to use System.Data.Linq.

Comment: Your Co-Worker is missing .net 3.5, which is a download from Microsoft.

Comment: Easy question, same answer 3 times during 10 seconds :-)

Comment: +1 for the footnote! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to deploy the .NET Framework 3.5 on to your target machine.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=333325fd-ae52-4e35-b531-508d977d32a6&displaylang=en

Comment: Exactly. If you want to make it "standalone" you can use an installer like NSIS (see url) to package it all together, though .NET 3.5 is a prett large install. http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

Update to .NET 3.5 on your coworker's machine and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Check the target machine has the correct version of .Net installed - you can use the [smallestdotnet.com](http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/) site to check

It will need the same .Net 3.5 version that you developed for

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before - it seems to be that there is a missing reference on System.Core

open your .csproj file and add a line similar to the following:

then restart your visual studio instance - this should work

paul